# How to use "OR" and pipe in windows powershell command for findstr

Tags: powershell, cmd

I am trying to parse below Powershell command for getting list of mac address

```
getmac | findstr "Device" | select-string '(..-){5}' | ForEach-Object{$_ -replace '^(..-..-..-..-..-..).+$','$1'}
```

it gives me output like

```
7C-05-07-0F-F8-69
```

I want to add one more check to check if it is start with specific range
as below

```
getmac | findstr "Device" | findstr "7C:05:07" | findstr "08:00:27" | findstr "00:50:56" | select-string '(..-){5}' | ForEach-Object{$_ -replace '^(..-..-..-..-..-..).+$','$1'}
```

But this `findstr "Device" | findstr "7C:05:07" | findstr "08:00:27" | findstr "00:50:56"`

Does not work as or operation i tried below also

```
 getmac | (findstr "Device" -or findstr "7C:05:07" -or findstr "08:00:27" -or findstr "00:50:56")
```

it gives error in powershell Please help

Comment: Please add the error you get

Comment: Guessing the error is `Expressions are only allowed as the first element of a pipeline.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks Matt for detailed answer.

I also found a solution for a same problem i would like to post my answer.

We can use `/c` option from `findstr` for or operation in command prompt and powershell blow how i did

```
getmac | findstr "Device" | findstr /c:"00-15-5D" /c:"08-00-27" /c:"00-50-56" /c:"52-54-00"| select-string '(..-){5}' | ForEach-Object{$_ -replace '^(..-..-..-..-..-..).+$','$1'}
```

Please refer this link for more information about [findstr](http://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html)

Answer (score 2):

You are getting an error because of the poorly formed expression in your last example. I imagine the error you are getting is: `Expressions are only allowed as the first element of a pipeline.`

You can't use `-or` in the way you are doing. Each side of the operator will be evaluated as a boolean. And while we can do that with subexpressions that might not get results you expect.

In general I would suggest just using this to remove the need for all the findstr's

```
getmac | select-string "[-A-F0-9]{17}" -AllMatches | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Matches | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Value
```

Then we could filter from there using `-or`

```
 getmac | select-string "[-A-F0-9]{17}" -AllMatches | 
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty Matches | 
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty Value | 
    Where-Object{$_ -match "7C:05:07" -or $_ -match "08:00:27" -or $_ -match "00:50:56"}
```

I would do something a little more terse with regex.

```
getmac | select-string "[-A-F0-9]{17}" -AllMatches | 
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty Matches | 
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty Value | 
    Where-Object{$_ -match "7C:05:07|08:00:27|00:50:56"}
```

If those have to be at the beginning you could change the last regex to the following:  `"^(7C:05:07|08:00:27|00:50:56)"`

I would also consider just querying WMI for this information instead of text parsing.

```
Get-WmiObject win32_networkadapter | Where-Object{$_.MacAddress} | Select -ExpandProperty macaddress
```

Comment: +1 from my side for giving brief description and nice solution It can be done using findstr i found solution for it please review my answer on same question